# Matrix within matrix with numbering

Tags: matrices, arrays

What is the best way to create the below matrix in LaTeX?

[image: matix in matrix]

I tried two ways

**1)** 
using `gather`, `pmatrix` and `vmatrix` inside but cannot get the desired formatting

```
\begin{gather}
\begin{pmatrix} 
    \begin{vmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\  x_{21} & x_{22}\\ \end{vmatrix}
 \\ y \\ z\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{gather}
```

**2)** 
I get the right format using two arrays but the numbering (`gather`) doesn't work

```
\begin{gather}
\[\left(
\begin{array}{cr}
    \left| \begin{array}{cr}
     x_{11} & x_{12} \\  x_{21} & x_{22} \end{array}\right| \\ y \\ z \\
\end{array}
\right)\]
\end{gather}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `gather` for a single equation. Anyway, the second example is wrong because you must not have `\[...\]` inside a math display.

The image shows too wide spaces around the fences; it was probably obtained with `array`.

I'll present three possibilities, in order of preference. Here I use three consecutive `equation` environment just because they're independent examples; for groups of consecutive equations, `gather` or `align` should obviously be used in a real document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{vmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\  x_{21} & x_{22} \end{vmatrix}
 \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
\;\begin{vmatrix} x_{11} & x_{12} \\  x_{21} & x_{22} \end{vmatrix}\;
 \\ y \\ z
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
  \left|\begin{array}{cc}
    x_{11} & x_{12} \\  x_{21} & x_{22}
  \end{array}\right|
  \\ y \\ z
  \end{array}
\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]